# Toggle boolean attribute via checkbox instantly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tasks in my app with boolean attribute 'completed'. I would like to be able to check the checkbox and to instantly change that boolean attribute from false to true ( and not have to click the submit button ). How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
<script>        
    function toggle(id, value)
    {
       document.getElementById('img').src = "scriptURL?id=" + id+ "&value=" + value;   } 
 </script>  

 <input type="checkbox" name="toggleBox" onclick="toggle(this.id,this.checked);"/>

 <img src="scriptURL" id="img" style="display:none;"/>
```

The image is hidden, when you click the checkbox it sends a message to the image to re-load from "scriptURL".

"ScriptURL" recieves the name of the control and the value - your code can pick these up from the query string and process them.

It's completely transparent to the user and doesn't need any additional frameworks.

Or

```
<script>

    function toggle(id, value)
    {
       var url = "scriptURL?id=" + id+ "&value=" + value; 

       // this sends the name and value parameters to the scriptURL
       $("<div/>").html(url);
    } 


    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".toggleBox").bind("click", function(){
            toggle($(this).attr("id"), $(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });

</script>


<input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" class="toggleBox" />
```

Ruby script:

```
...
require 'cgi' 

params = CGI.parse(request.query_string) 
# params is now {"id"=>["id name"], "value"=>["true or false"]} 

**Completed = p['value'].first** 

... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: ok, but I don't understand what you wrote. Can you please clarify or point me to some noob-friendly AJAX with Rails tutorial?

Comment: I posted the question similar to this but I got further in my travels... :) if you'd be so kind and look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656860/change-attribute-using-checkbox-ajax-jquery